# Running A Python Script Using ./scriptName.py

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to create an executable file that can be executed as follows:

```
./scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The code compiles and runs if I use:

```
python ./scriptname.py
```

If I try using the desired command, I get an error stating: from: can't read /var/mail/sys

The beginning of my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sys import *

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Any help on getting my executable in the proper command format would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What OS? What's the output if you run `which python` in the terminal?

Comment: have you made the script executable?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, trying to execute through Terminal.  I'm not very familiar with Python and its compiling processes, so I'm not sure if I'm supposed to compile first and then try and execute it like I am.  If that's the case, some advice on that front would be greatly appreciated.  As for running `which python` I get `/usr/bin/local/python`. And I have used `chmod +x` to make the script executable.

Comment: Use `import sys` instead of `from sys import *`

Comment: Using `import sys` instead results in a different error: `import: command not found`.

Comment: You're telling it to use python at `/usr/bin/python` is that what you actually want or do you want to use `/usr/bin/local/python`?

Comment: Using either one doesn't seem to make a difference.  I adjusted to `/usr/bin/local/python` and still receive the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure there's no newline, space, invisible character, etc. before the `#!`? Because this is clearly running your script with `sh` rather than `python`, which means it's not seeing your shbang line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to specify an interpreter from a script, the `#!` must literally be the first two bytes in the file.

If you have a newline, a space, a UTF-8 BOM, an invisible character, etc. before the `#`, then it's not a shebang line. If you've saved the file as UTF-16 so the file starts with the equivalent ASCII bytes `#\0!\0`, it's not a shebang line.

If there's no shebang line, the script is run by your default shell. That means the `from sys import *` line is interpreted by running the `from` command, as in `/usr/bin/from`, which treats its first argument as a username, and looks for the mail spool for the user `sys`, which doesn't exist. And the `import sys` line is interpreted by running the `import` command, which doesn't exist.

To see what the raw bytes of your file are, you can use the `hexdump` command that comes built in with OS X. For example:

```
$ hexdump -n16 -C ./goodscript.py
00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 70  |#!/usr/bin/env p|
$ hexdump -n16 -C ./badscript.py
00000000  00 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20  |.#!/usr/bin/env |
```

That first one starts with a shebang line that runs python (via the `env` tool). The second one starts with a NUL byte (note the `00 23 21` instead of `23 21`—or, more simply, the `.#!` instead of `#!` in the right column), so it runs the shell.

---

Meanwhile, if you just run `./scriptname`, that's literally trying to run a program named `scriptname`, with no extension. Unix isn't like Windows, where it tries to guess at different extensions like `scriptname.exe` or `scriptname.bat` or `scriptname.py` until one of them works.

So, if you want it to be runnable as `./scriptname`, you have to rename, hardlink, symlink, or copy `scriptname.py` to `scriptname`. In descending order from what (I'd guess) you want most to least:

- `mv scriptname.py scriptname` *renames* the file. This means you no longer have a file named `scriptname.py` at all, only a file named `scriptname`. This is the simplest choice. But it does mean that you now have to edit `scriptname`, not `scriptname.py`, and so forth, and `scriptname` will have a generic Finder icon and so forth. This can also be a problem is `scriptname.py` is meant to be usable as a module to be `import`ed in other Python scripts, as well as a script to be run directly. But again, if none of these are a problem, it's the simplest choice.
- `ln -s scriptname.py scriptname` *symlinks* the file. This means `scriptname` is now a special "link file" pointing at `scriptname.py`; when you type `./scriptname`, OS X will effectively treat that as a shortcut for typing `./scriptname.py`. This means you can still edit (and `import`, and so on) `scriptname.py`, but run it as `./scriptname`.
- `ln scriptname.py scriptname` *hardlinks* the file. (Notice the lack of `-s` this time.) This means the two names are just different names for the same file on disk. This has a similar effect to the previous one, but it's less obvious what's going on, so it's probably not what you want.
- `cp scriptname.py scriptname` *copies* the file. This means if you later edit `scriptname.py`, that will have no effect on `./scriptname` unless you repeat the copy (because they're entirely separate files). This is almost always a recipe for disaster; one day you will forget the copy, and spent four hours debugging something that you *know* you fixed because the fix didn't make it to the script you're actually running.

One common thing to do is leave it as `scriptname.py` in your development directory, but once you've got it working, install it to somewhere on your PATH as `scriptname`. For example, `install -m755 scriptname.py /usr/local/bin/scriptname`. Then, you don't have to (in fact, can't) run it as `./scriptname`, you just run it as `scriptname`. However, if this is what you want, you're really better off not doing it manually, but instead learning how to build Python distribution packages and writing a `setup.py` that does the right thing on every platform, handles user-vs.-system-wide installs, etc.

Comment: Awesome, this almost solved it.  Now I can run the script fine using `./scriptname.py`, but still cannot run it using JUST `./scriptname`.  Is there another piece I'm still missing?

Comment: @user3233838: Well, are those the same file? Or is one a symlink to the other or something? If not… that's your problem. Extensions are part of the filename in Unix; it's only in Windows that you can leave them off.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm definitely getting closer.  After installing the script on my PATH, I can run it using JUST `scriptname`.  I'm normally not so picky, but believe that this file cannot be handled unless it is in the exact format required, which is `./scriptname`.  Can the above advice be altered in a way that it will run using the `./` before it?

Comment: @user3233838: In that case, don't install it on the path; just do what the previous paragraph suggests: rename, hardlink, symlink, or copy the script to `scriptname`. (I assume you know the differences between the four, and how to do whichever one you want?)

Comment: I actually do not.  If you could suggest which option is best and give me a quick idea of how to do it, that would be super awesome and much appreciated!

Comment: @user3233838: OK, edited into the answer. But if you need more guidance beyond that, you should probably go to SuperUser or a Unix users' site.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much again.  You've been a huge help!